# throws error with Multiple Joins and query is running for long time

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I tried to pull the data from multiple table but due to billions of data i fetched data by year and month. Query is running for long time and throwing space error. The temp space was increased to maximum size still the error is throwing.

Query as follows :

```
select DISTINCT 'NEW_TEST' as DIL
      ,(nvl(to_char(erg.rdrgrp_id), 'MASTER')) as PIN_ID
      ,ws.wrks_id as time_code
      ,ws.emp_id as NEW1
      ,(select emp_name
          from employee
         where emp_id = ws.emp_id) as employee_number
      ,wd.tcode_id as pay_code_id
      ,ws.wrks_tcode_sum as timesheet_entry_type
      ,wd.tcode_id as time_code
      ,wd.htype_name as hour_type
      ,(select htype_desc
          from hour_type
         where htype_name = wd.htype_name) as hour_type_desc
      ,null as hour_type_detail
      ,(wd.wrkd_minutes / 60) as timesheet_hours
      ,wd.tcode_id as pay_code_id
      ,ws.paygrp_id as pay_group_code
      ,(select paygrp_name
          from pay_group
         where paygrp_id = ws.paygrp_id) as pay_group_name
      ,ws.wrks_rules_applied as work_rule_desc
      ,wd.wrkd_overridden as time_entry_source_adjusted
      ,ws.shft_id as work_shift_id
      ,(select shft_name
          from shift
         where shft_id = ws.shft_id) as work_shift
      ,wd.job_id as job_code
      ,(select job_desc
          from job
         where job_id = wd.job_id) as job_desc
      ,wd.client_id as client
      ,wd.wrkd_rate as rate
      ,(select paygrptyp_name
          from view_pay_group
         where paygrp_id = ws.paygrp_id) as rate_uom
      ,(wd.wrkd_rate * wd.wrkd_minutes) / 60 as wage
      ,(select sum(wd.wrkd_minutes / 60 * wd.wrkd_rate)
          from work_detail wd
         where wd.wrks_id = ws.wrks_id) as amount
      ,wd.proj_id as project_number
      ,wd.proj_name as project_name
  from work_summary          ws
      ,employee_reader_group erg
      ,view_work_detail      wd
      ,employee_schedule     es
 where ws.emp_id = erg.emp_id
   and ws.wrks_id = wd.wrks_id
   and Ws.emp_id = es.emp_id
   and ws.wrks_work_date between ('01-JAN-2016') and ('31-MAR-2016');
```

Answer (score 0):

The ES table is not joined to anything

```
AND ES.EMP_ID   =ES.EMP_ID
```

should probably be:

```
AND WS.EMP_ID   =ES.EMP_ID
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typing mistake still it is not running as expected . Is there problem in using distinct?

Comment: There's no distinct in your query.

Comment: Oh there is now. Sorry for wasting my time.

Comment: I tried the query with and without Distinct .when using distinct it is taking long time to run.But I want the data to be unique.Please suggest me on it